# finding character count between two special symbols

Tags: java

Am trying to find the character count between `=` and `\n` new line character using below java code. But `\n` is not considering in my case.

am using `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;` package

Please find my below java code.

```
public class CharCountInLine {
    
     public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
    
     BufferedReader reader = null;
 
     try
     {
                  
         reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\wordcount\\sample.txt"));
          
                 
         String currentLine = reader.readLine();
         
         String[] line = currentLine.split("=");

         
         while (currentLine != null ){
             String res = StringUtils.substringBetween(currentLine, "=", "\n"); //    \n is not working.
             if(res != null) {
             System.out.println("line -->"+res.length());
             }
             currentLine = reader.readLine();
         }
         
      } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally
     {
         try
         {
             reader.close();        
         }
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }

}
```

Please find my sample text file.

sample.txt

```
Karthikeyan=123456
sathis= 23546
Arun = 23564
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: If your keys are unique, you could probably get away with treating it like a [Java properties file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html). No need to parse it yourself then.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you're reading the string using `readLine()`, which according to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) (emphasis mine):

> **Returns:**
>
> A `String` containing the contents of the line, **not including
> any line-termination characters**, or null if the end of the stream has
> been reached

So your code doesn't work because the string does not contain a newline character.

---

You can address this in a number of ways:

- Use [`StringUtils.substringAfter()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringAfter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) instead of `StringUtils.substringBetween()`.
- If it meets the requirements, treat your file as a [`Java properties file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) so you don't need to parse it yourself.
- Use [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).
- Use [`String.lastIndexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-).
- Some simple regex matching and grouping.

Comment: Maybe also recommend using try-with-resources when reading the text file?

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to change how you read the lines, simply change your logic to extract the text after `=`.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:.+)=(.+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Karthikeyan=123456");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1).length());
}
```

No need for Apache StringUtils either, simple Java regex will do. If you don't want to count whitespace, trim the string before calling `length()`.

Alternatively, you can also split the line around `=` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/839733).

10x simpler code:

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:\\wordcount\\sample.txt");
Files.lines(p)
  .forEach { line ->
    // Put the above code here
}
```